# Issue with collatz conjecture in python, loop ends far too early

Tags: python, python-3.x

I wrote a program to check the highest number of steps of the collatz conjecture in a range. However, the number I get is incorrect, it appears that the loop ends far too early. Can anyone tell me what is wrong with my code? I checked multiple times over different ranges and each time it is still wrong.

```
def collatz_sequence(n):
    sequence = []
    while n != 1:
        sequence.append(n)
        if n % 2 == 0:
            n = n // 2
        elif n % 2 != 0:
            n = 3 * n + 1
    return sequence

max_len = 1
for i in range(1, 1000):
    if len(collatz_sequence(i)) > max_len:
        max_len = i
        print(max_len)
```

Comment: Side note: that `elif` is just `else`. What do you get and what do you expect and why?

Comment: @Andras Deak wikipedia said the longest sequence under 1000 is 178 resulting from an i of 871, so I expect 871 instead of 313. btw thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: Also, it works fine under 100, but once the loop reaches 313 it just stops

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are setting `max_len` to the index of the longest sequence, not its length. You want to keep track of the length of the longest sequence seen so far (and update it for longer sequences as they are seen), rather than its position in the first 1000 sequences. Try:

```
def collatz_sequence(n):
    sequence = []
    while n != 1:
        sequence.append(n)
        if n % 2 == 0:
            n = n // 2
        elif n % 2 != 0:
            n = 3 * n + 1
    return sequence

max_len = 1
for i in range(1, 1000):
    seq_len = len(collatz_sequence(i))
    if seq_len > max_len:
        max_len = seq_len
        print(i, max_len)


3 7
6 8
7 16
9 19
18 20
25 23
27 111
54 112
73 115
97 118
129 121
171 124
231 127
313 130
327 143
649 144
703 170
871 178
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer, but could you explain"You are setting max_len to the index of the longest sequence, not its length." in a bit more depth, please?

Comment: Nevermind, I completely understand how I was getting that error. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

you want to store `len(collatz_sequence(i))` in `max_len`:

```
max_len = 1
for i in range(1, 1000):
    l = len(collatz_sequence(i))
    if l > max_len:
        max_len = l
        print(i, max_len)
```